# Screen Capture / Saving CSS3 to image somehow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screenshot

I have a div that's 512x512 and the user can drag/drop stuff around.

I would like to save this for use in an email which doesn't support many CSS properties.

My initial idea was to take a screenshot and crop it but I can't seem to find a good way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this and wrote a blog post on it here - http://jbeas.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-screenshot-pdf-gem/